# Static front page - going against the grain

Tags: frontpage

My theme uses front-page.php. That is currently my front page.

I want the main website URL to go to a new custom page, and I want the old front-page.php to be functional.

I've tried changing Reading -> Static Page   to be the new front page, but it's not overriding my settings.

Why? I see a million articles on setting the reading section, and I understand I could change the default wordpress page hierarchy, but there should be an easier way?

I see this, but it's not exactly the same:
[Static Front Page problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47663/static-front-page-problem)

Thank you anyone who is so kind.

Comment: What does " old front-page.php to be functional" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a front-page.php template, I think this will get used, even if you change the Reading -> Static Page settings:

If you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page you'll see:

'On the site front page, WordPress will always use the front-page.php template file, if it exists. If front-page.php does not exist, WordPress will determine which template file to use, depending on the user configuration of 'Settings > Reading ->Front page displays', as follows:'

You could rename your new home page template to be front-page.php and rename the old (current) front-page.php so that it can be used as a template on another page.

Another useful read is the template hierarcy:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: I chose with not having a front-page.php. Per your remarks, this allowed me to use the 'Settings > Reading ->Front page displays' section to set my front page to what I want.

Kind of a pain, because that setting should overwrite your actual front page all together! 

When i tried renaming my new front page to front-page.php and renamed the old. Then the old page would be empty if I tried browsing to it.

So now wordpress will load my new front page based on the reading section (Splash Page) and load my previous front page as secondary page via my menu (Front End).